# Boring holes in 6x6 beam

Tags: beam

My ranch style house was built between 1940-1955. Below you will see a 6x6 beam running parallel with the ceiling joists. The 6x6 beam is a wall that is not in the center of the house exactly. Should I be worried about the hole that was bored to run camera security wiring down into the wall? The wiring hasn’t been placed in there yet. It’s sitting around in the attic.

The first picture shows the beam running parrallel with the ceiling joists. It’s 6x6 beam. The second picture should show where the beam meets the center beams running the length of the house(I assume). The third picture shows the wall I am talking about that has the beam directly above it. The last picture shows the wall I’m talking about meeting the center load bearing wall that runs the length of my house.

Thank you for any help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Im just worried that it’s load bearing and the 2 inch hole drilled vertically into the 6x6 beam could pose a problem.

Comment: So there’s a wall below the 6x6 beam...??? Does it run parallel or perpendicular to the beam and is it located directly below the 2” hole?

Comment: Yes, it’s directly below the beam. The beam runs the length of the wall. I have a ranch style house, 75ft long by 24 ft wide, 1800sq ft total. The length of the wall is 12 ft. On one side of the wall is the office and the other side is my laundry room and a closet. The 2inch hole that is drilled into the 6x6 beam is sitting on the 2x4‘s that make up the wall. I’m sorry if I’m not explains it well. I wish I could add more pictures to this question.

Comment: It sounds like your house is framed post and beam style with the post and beam running down the center of the house.  You then have joists perpendicular to this post and beam sitting on the post/beam on each side of the house.  The 6x6 is then running  inline with the joists - why they'd put a 6x6 here instead of joists isn't clear to me.  Are your joists 2x6" 16" oc?  It looks like on one side of the 6x6 they are taller?

Comment: You're asking if you should be worried about a hole we cannot see in a beam we cannot see.  It's really difficult to say anything in this case.  Please fix your photos to show the actual items of concern.

Comment: Fresh Codemonger— I added a couple more photos of the hole/beam. Yes, The joist to the right of this beam is 2x6x16. I have looked at a couple other walls in the attic and I’m seeing the same thing, they placed beams in them as well. This specific beam that has the big hole in it has 2 smaller ones running electric down into the wall.

Comment: That looks like the top plate of a wall, not a beam. Beams don't usually run parallel to roof framing. Do you have any reason to think it carries load? Exactly how thick is it?

Comment: Isherwood, the piece of wood is 6in wide and 6in deep and should be 16 inches long, just as the joists are. I assumed that because it was at the top of a wall and attached to the center ”beam,” that it was potentially holding a load. The second picture where my foot is pointing and where you see the black electrical tape, the top plate meets the joist that stretches to the front of the house along with the I assume beams that run the entire length of my house.